# Get country value from Google API - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to get the country name and store in a scope variable from Google API.below is the code.but the function $scope.getLatLon is not returning the desired output.What am I doing wrong.I am new to AngularJS please help.

```
        // Find the country from LatLon

        $scope.lat = undefined;
        $scope.lng = undefined;
        $scope.country = undefined;
        $scope.city = undefined;
        $scope.region = undefined;
        $scope.city_name = undefined;

        $scope.getLatLon = function(val) {
            return $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
                params: {
                    address: val,
                    sensor: false,
                    key: 'AIzaSyDf2okPFXyT1yUT0wNT-3w-PY4vQuj1k40'
                }
            }).then(function(response) {

                var LatLon = response.data.results.map(function(item) {
                    return item.geometry;
                });

                console.log("ll : " + LatLon);

                var ll = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < LatLon.length; i++) {
                    var value = LatLon[i]['location'];
                    if (ll.indexOf(value) == -1) {
                        ll.push(value);
                    }
                }

                $scope.lat = ll[0].lat;
                $scope.lng = ll[0].lng;

                var results = response.data.results;

                if (results) {
                    var indice = 0;
                    for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                        if (results[j].types[0] == 'locality') {
                            indice = j;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < results[j].address_components.length; i++) {
                        if (results[j].address_components[i].types[0] == "locality") {

                            var city = results[j].address_components[i];
                        }
                        if (results[j].address_components[i].types[0] == "administrative_area_level_1") {

                            var region = results[j].address_components[i];
                        }
                        if (results[j].address_components[i].types[0] == "country") {

                            var country = results[j].address_components[i];
                        }
                    }
                    $scope.city = city.long_name;
                    $scope.region = region.long_name;
                    $scope.country = country.long_name;
                    //city data
                    console.log(city.long_name + " || " + region.long_name + " || " + country.short_name)


                } else {
                    console.log("No results found");
                }


                var lat = $scope.lat;
                var lng = $scope.lng;

                var distance = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat, lng, 8.3764707, 78.0562522);

                // set_country(country.long_name);

                console.log(distance);
                console.log("country_in : " + country.long_name);

                return country.long_name;
            });

        };

        console.log($scope.getLatLon);//= "France";
        $scope.hotels = HotelService.query({

            city_name: $scope.country
        });
```

Comment: What error are you getting in the console?

Comment: Rias,Thanks.I can see the values for 'console.log(distance);
                console.log("country_in : " + country.long_name);' correctly but the country.long_name is not getting returned.

Comment: I am getting the value for $scope.getLatLong as undefined.

Comment: do `$scope.$apply()` to run the digest cycle will update the scope

Comment: Hi Pankaj,could you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: `$http.get()` returns a promise - not the value you are returning in your `then`-Callback. Thats the main problem here.

Comment: I have updated my original code on how i am planning to use $scope.country.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you could do something like this

```
$scope.getLatLon = function(val) {
   return $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
     {
        params: {
        address: val,
        sensor: false,
        key: 'AIzaSyDf2okPFXyT1yUT0wNT-3w-PY4vQuj1k40'
     }
   }).then(function(response) { 
        // something    
        $scope.countryLongName = country.long_name; 
   })};
```

and then use the `$scope.countryLongName` wherever you need.

Comment: I did.but $scope.countryLongName is still showing undefined outside the scope.

Comment: @SudhakarCamilos Then did you check if your `country.long_name` has a value in the first place ?

Comment: Yes,inside the function country.long_name has a value.but not outside the function scope

Answer (score 0):

Fixed code
HTML:

```
 <input type="text" ng-model="address"/>
  <button ng-click="getLatLon()">Get location</button>
  <div>{{lat}}</div>
  <div>{{address}}</div>
  <div>{{lng}}</div>
  <div>{{country}}</div>
  <div>{{city}}</div>
  <div>{{region}}</div>
  <div>{{city_name}}</div>
```

JS:

```
 $scope.lat = undefined;
    $scope.address = undefined;
    $scope.lng = undefined;
    $scope.country = undefined;
    $scope.city = undefined;
    $scope.region = undefined;
    $scope.city_name = undefined;

    $scope.getLatLon = function() {
      alert("called");
      return $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
        params: {
          address: $scope.address,
          sensor: false,
          key: 'AIzaSyDf2okPFXyT1yUT0wNT-3w-PY4vQuj1k40'
        }
      }).then(function(response) {
        var LatLon = response.data.results.map(function(item) {
          return item.geometry;
        });

        console.log("ll : " + LatLon);

        var ll = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < LatLon.length; i++) {
          var value = LatLon[i]['location'];
          if (ll.indexOf(value) == -1) {
            ll.push(value);
          }
        }

        $scope.lat = ll[0].lat;
        $scope.lng = ll[0].lng;

        var results = response.data.results;

        if (results) {
          var indice = 0;
          for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
            if (results[j].types[0] == 'locality') {
              indice = j;
              break;
            }
          }

          for (var i = 0; i < results[j].address_components.length; i++) {
            if (results[j].address_components[i].types[0] == "locality") {

              var city = results[j].address_components[i];
            }
            if (results[j].address_components[i].types[0] == "administrative_area_level_1") {

              var region = results[j].address_components[i];
            }
            if (results[j].address_components[i].types[0] == "country") {

              var country = results[j].address_components[i];
            }
          }
          $scope.city = city.long_name;
          $scope.region = region.long_name;
          $scope.country = country.long_name;
          //city data
          console.log(city.long_name + " || " + region.long_name + " || " + country.short_name)


        } else {
          console.log("No results found");
        }


        var lat = $scope.lat;
        var lng = $scope.lng;

        var distance = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat, lng, 8.3764707, 78.0562522);

        // set_country(country.long_name);

        console.log(distance);
        console.log("country_in : " + country.long_name);

        return country.long_name;
      });

    };

    console.log($scope.getLatLon);//= "France";
```

You need inject $http to controller
and implement function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm

Comment: Oleksander Lubushyn Thanks.This is working,but my requirement is to use the $scope.getLatLon an argument inside the controller.

Comment: like
       $scope.hotels = HotelService.query({
            city_name: $scope.getLatLon
        });